# Stop parallax efect when image goes out of limits

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I'm using stellar.js to my parallax. It works ok, but I think a good improvement it could be detect when the top or the bottom borders of an image goes out of limits, (you see the image edge), so when this happen, the parallax effect should stop and the velocity of scroll of the image gets equals to the scrolling velocity. So you will never see any image edge, or any image repetition in case of use (background-repeat: repeat;) I really don't know how to implement this. If somebody can help me with this it would be nice.

Answer (score 0):

You could check if an image reached the top or bottom of another element with [getBoundingClientRect](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/getBoundingClientRect), which gives you an object informing the absolute coordinates of an element's sides relative to the viewport.

Assuming a layout of this kind:

```
       topEl  
 +----------------+    
____________________
 |     image      |
____________________
 +----------------+  
      bottomEl
```

JavaScript:

```
var imageRect    = image.getBoundingClientRect();
var topElRect    = topEl.getBoundingClientRect();
var bottomElRect = bottomEl.getBoundingClientRect();

if (imageRect.top >= topElRect.bottom ||
    imageRect.bottom <= bottomElRect.top) {
   // Stop scrolling
}
```

Feel free to update with more details if you want a more precise explanation.

Comment: The difficult part is to detect when start again the parallax effect for example if you change your scroll direction after stop parallax effect

Comment: Can't you just do the contrary, ie.:  `if (imageRect.top <= topElRect.bottom ||
    imageRect.bottom >= bottomElRect.top) {
   // Start scrolling again
}`

Comment: How I include this properties. Where is the js file to download. Thanks

Comment: ok it's included with the browsers but I get this error: Uncaught TypeError: jQuery(...).getBoundingClientRect is not a function

Comment: Yes that's because you're dealing with a jQuery object and not a native DOM element object, and `getBoundingClientRect` is a method of native element objects. To get a native element from a jQuery object: `myJQueryObject[0]`

Comment: I cant make it run. Could you please explain me with a real example. Because I don't know how to make reference to an object with out jQuery. Thanks in advanced

Comment: `var jQueryElement = $('#whatever'); var normalElement = jQueryElement[0]`